# Jenkins helm chart - job DSL issue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl, jcasc

I have created a PipelineJob in Jenkins UI, which calls 2 other Jenkins jobs:

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage("Trigger disable script approval") {
            steps {
                script{
                    build job: 'Tools/Disable_Script_Approval'
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Trigger Jobs loading into Jenkins") {
            steps {
                script{
                    build job: 'Tools/Seed_Job_Executor'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I used **xml-job-to-job-dsl** plugin in order to get the job syntax in DSL:

```
pipelineJob("testLior") {
    description()
    keepDependencies(false)
    definition {
        cpsScm {
"""pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage("Trigger disable script approval") {
            steps {
                script{
                    build job: 'Tools/Disable_Script_Approval'
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Trigger Jobs loading into Jenkins") {
            steps {
                script{
                    build job: 'Tools/Seed_Job_Executor'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}"""        }
    }
    disabled(false)
    configure {
        it / 'properties' / 'com.sonyericsson.rebuild.RebuildSettings' {
            'autoRebuild'('false')
            'rebuildDisabled'('false')
        }
    }
}
```

I took the above code, and tried to use in JCasC configuration (we are running Jenkins with helm chart on top of EKS), and created this values file:

```
controller:
  JCasC:
    configScripts:
      casc-jobs: |
        jobs:
        - script: >
          pipelineJob('DSL_Seed_Job') {
            definition {
              cpsScm {
                '''pipeline {
                    agent any 
                    stages {
                        stage('Trigger disable script approval') {
                            steps {
                                script{
                                    build job: 'Tools/Disable_Script_Approval'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        stage('Trigger Jobs loading into Jenkins') {
                            steps {
                                script{
                                    build job: 'Tools/Seed_Job_Executor'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }'''    
              }
            }
          }
...
...
```

So once I'm running **helm upgrade** I see that Jenkins pod fails to read the JCasC jobs configuration, and this error message appears:

```
2021-10-21 11:04:37.178+0000 [id=22]    SEVERE  hudson.util.BootFailure#publish: Failed to initialize Jenkins
while scanning a simple key
 in /var/jenkins_home/casc_configs/casc-jobs.yaml, line 3, column 3:
      pipelineJob('DSL_Seed_Job') {
      ^
could not find expected ':'
 in /var/jenkins_home/casc_configs/casc-jobs.yaml, line 12, column 38:
     ...                        build job: 'Tools/Disable_Script_Approval'
```

What can be the cause for this error? I got the DSL syntax from the **xml-job-to-dsl-job** Jenkins plugin so I don't understand what am I missing here.

Thanks in advance,
Lior

Answer (score 0):

You probably figured this out by now but it looks to me like a yaml indentation issue, I believe the block starting with "pipelineJob" should be indented like so:

```
jobs:
- script: >
    pipelineJob('DSL_Seed_Job') {
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Hello 

Actually, I didn't manage to get it working.
I'll test it out and update whether it worked or not.
Thank you